# React component not render anything, except after I refresh page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react router, but when I change page my component doesn't render anything just show white page, but it render when page refreshing

This is my route list:
[routes.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzqcR.png)

And this is my App.tsx :
[App.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYESu.png)

index.tsx:
[index.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDRPN.png)

Comment: Add your code in a sandbox

Comment: Can you explain what you've seen before and after page refreshing ? DId you check the console logs in dev tools ?

Comment: Don't post images of code. Post the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the empty container <> </> use switch to wrap your routes

```
<Switch> 
...routes

</Switch>
```

then you can just import it as you were without the switch enclosing as:

```
<Suspense>
  <Routes />
</Suspense>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<Route>` must be covered by `<Switch></Switch>` and `<BrowserRouter></BrowserRouter>` tags imported from `import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";`  Like this:

```js
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";


const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/Home">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You can add a Navigation component and set The Links to Route to other components:\

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Nav = () => {
  return (
      <Link to="Home" >
        Home
      </Link>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

Please place your code in a sandbox so people can understand more clearly

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the wrapping of your Switch and Routes with  `<BrowserRouter>`.  You may use `BrowserRouter as Router`

Check the basic example.

https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic

Answer (score 0):

You need to Import `BrowserRouter` instead of `Router` from `react-router-dom`

try

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch  } from 'react-router-dom';
```

instead of

```
import { Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue..
Figured I had  enveloping each button.. rather than all buttons
Fixed with revised code below (using v6)

```
<BrowserRouter>

      <div className = "container">

          <Navbar />

          <Routes>  

            <Route 
              path="/"
              element = {user ? <Dashboard /> : <Navigate to="/login" /> }
            />
            

            <Route 
              path="/feedback"
              element = { user ? <Feedback /> : <Navigate to="/login" /> }
            />
          

            <Route 
              path="/login"
              element = { !user ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/" /> }
              
            />

          </Routes>

          </div>

      </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove the React Strict Mode from index.js when using react router